# Why are my hyperlink addresses showing up next to the link its self?

Tags: hyperlink, parentheses

For example...

I have a link to the home page but when I view the page it looks something like this

HOME (http://www.gotohomepage.com)

Why is the link showing in parentheses next to the link its self?  I just want it to be HOME with no link after it.  It is only showing up in chrome, no problem with IE.

Here is my code...

```
<p><a href="http://www.gotohompage.com">Home</a></p>
```

And no this obviously is not the real linked address but is similar in structure

Comment: Need more info. Are you using an IDE like Dreamweaver to edit. It could also be a setting in your browser.

Comment: Yes I am using Dreamweaver.  I am more familiar with visual studio but I am having to use dreamweaver at work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have a chrome extension installed?

Can you list which one(s)?

My guess is that one of them is the culprit.  Or it's a new setting in chrome I haven't seen before.

Comment: All I have done is installed Chrome from the chrome download site.  No extensions have been added or installed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok it appears that all I had to do to fix this issue was go into chromes settings and check the ssl 2.0 box.  Everything works now.  Thanks for those who responded.